# Responsive design: viewport isn't being applied properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here is my website, [www.offergrind.com](http://www.offergrind.com)

I made it fully non-responsive but the problem is that if we view it in mobile it is displaying the top left part.

Is there any code such as

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=SITE_MIN_WIDTH, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

**What should i do to make the website to display fit in mobile view ?**

Comment: You mention you made it fully non-responsive, it seems you know you should be looking for notes on responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this. At minimal, it will make your website fit the device, but everything will be sized down.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

You should also look in `CSS pre-processors`, I was blown away by how many CSS files you reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the viewport `meta` tag altogether. If your website was not designed to be responsive, it will only make things worse. See this for more:

**[Stop using the viewport meta tag (until you know how to use it)](http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the below meta tag for your website

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

The meta tag above explains everything:

width="device-width" width of the website is equal to device width

initial-scale=1.0 means the website will not scale to fit the device screen

when we set minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 and user-scalable=0 means user will not be able to scale the webpage (it will turn off pinch-zooming by setting maximum-scale to 1, or using user-scalable=no. )